# What are the pitfalls of calculating band gaps via density functional theory?

Tags: density-functional-theory

There are various questions on this SE that discuss DFT in terms of band gaps - [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/265/are-there-any-cases-where-lda-gga-overestimates-band-gaps-if-so-what-is-the-rea), [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1202/is-the-electronic-band-gap-the-only-thing-that-is-affected-when-switching-from), [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2378/is-there-an-energy-gap-correction-factor-that-needs-to-be-used-in-dft-calculatio), and elsewhere - but they touch upon different aspects.

P.S.: I'm asking this from the mind-frame of someone who doesn't know much more than how to put tags together in some DFT code's input file and get a shining, all-hail-lords-Kohn-and-Sham energy per atom value as the output.

Comment: I think there is an issue with your question. Band gap and Fermi energy are not DFT concepts.

Comment: It comes up often how due to the approximate nature of the xc functional, band-gaps calculated via DFT are underestimated. I was confused as to when DFT calculated fermi levels or band gaps can be reported. Please suggest appropriate changes for this question, thank you.

Comment: This can end up excessively broad.  Id suggest narrowing it to one or the other.  Dft often can only handle a band gap or Fermi level at the same time.  The fermi level of semiconductors is ill defined for dft.

Comment: @TristanMaxson restricted it to band gap.

Comment: Good decision.  The fermi level is a different topic potentially, but I fear there may not be a ton to say about it.

Comment: @TristanMaxson, no harm in asking I suppose. Here's one on fermi level: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3505/fermi-energy-in-density-functional-theory 

Comment: "Summarise/discuss **everything** about band gap in terms of DFT (all flavours) calculations." still seems excessively broad to me.

Comment: @Anyon one-topic-per-answer might help. This question could become a great resource in one page.

Comment: You are asking too general equation for the StackExchange Q&A format. This is not a forum in the conventional meaning.

Comment: Alright, should I edit the question to talk of Kohn Sham DFT? Frankly, my knowledge here is limited.

Comment: @HitanshuSachania. We already have 2 close votes for the question. The question is lacking clarity (not a specific question. summarize everything type question). It might be better to edit the question

Comment: @Thomas, I think this might be okay. It's still asking for everything but in a sort of cursory manner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The important thing to keep in mind is that the Kohn-Sham (KS) band gap is *not* the fundamental/quasiparticle gap. Even theoretically. This is not an 'underestimation' of the band gap. They are not the same gap.

The fundamental quasiparticle (QP) gap is calculated as the difference between valence band maxima and conduction band minima, but *for different hamiltonians*.

A part of the exchange-correlation potential called the response potential has changed in a discontinuous manner as you've added the new electron to see where your conduction band minima is. That added electron has changed the hamiltonian.

I think this little bit is really a dominant pitfall (I'm sure there are many others). It helps to keep in mind that **the KS gap is not the QP gap**. Even with the 'exact' KS functional, you wouldn't get the bandgap that compares favourably with experimental QP gaps.

Almost the entirety of the above rant has been taken from:

1. https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2017/cp/c7cp02123b#!divAbstract
2. https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2013/cp/c3cp52547c#!divAbstract

As above, I'm sure there are many other pitfalls, but this is the one I like to keep in mind the most.

Comment: This is a good, succinct answer. If you are interested in calculating band gaps, it's essential to understand exactly what you're calculating! Reading up on the K-S gap literature is a must.

Answer (score 2):

DFT is not applicable for computing the bandgap. If it gives it close to the experimental results, it is more or less accidentally. Usually, DFT is used as a basis set generator for subsequent computations based on GW theory or TDDFT.

DFT is by definition the ground-state theory - all Kohn-Sham theorems constituting the basis of DFT have been derived regarding the ground state properties. Also, there is no proof (at least I have not seen any) that Kohn-Sham orbitals can be somehow related to the excited states. The bandgap is a property related to the excited states though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you elaborate on why DFT is not applicable for computing the band gap?

Comment: This answer dismisses what can be calculated.  I strongly agree that DFT is not applicable for computing the band gap in terms of absolute value (although some improvements exist to allow for this).  However trends and band structures still tend to be useful.  This is not really an answer to the question.

Comment: As suggested by @TristanMaxson, the answer can have much more details. Please elaborate your answer

Comment: @TristanMaxson, I am very glad that you strongly agree with my statement. Can you specify in more detail what do you mean by "absolute value", is this something like |Eg|?

Comment: I mean the absolute value as in the quantitative value.  As in 3.2 eV experimental value of anatase TiO2 compared to computational values.  Rather than looking at absolute values, we can look at relative values.  DFT likely predicts rutile to have a lower band gap than anatase for example.

Comment: @Tristan Maxson how do you know that this prediction is correct and not accidental? Does theory guarantee it? So you can guarantee that the correlation effects beyond DFT have zero effect on the trend?

Comment: No, but this question asks what can we do with dft. Saying nothing is invalid

Comment: @Tristan Maxson I did not say it can do nothing

Comment: Based on your edits I am willing to give it the +1, I still think it sells DFT a little short but I do agree that there is no proof that DFT can handle the excited states (even if there is quite a bit of evidence that it seems to regardless of the ability to prove it).

Comment: Good to see healthy conversation guys, just be careful not to click the "let's continue this conversation in chat" button, as I explained here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353643/391772

Comment: I disagree with this answer. My perspective is summarized in this answer on Physics SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176419/why-does-density-functional-theory-dft-underestimate-bandgaps/360454#360454 1. "By definition" DFT states that you can reconstruct the external potential (and thus the Hamiltonian) from the ground-state density. In principle this implies that also excited-state properties are encoded in the ground-state density. 2. The fundamental band gap can be calculated from the ground-state energies of differently charged systems, though this is not the KS band gap.

Comment: If so, why does it fails to predict band gaps for most of the crystalline materials?

Comment: How about the reconstruction of the many-body potential like V(r1, r2)?